# How to change "other names" in my Google Plus basic info

Tags: google-plus

I want to change "other names" in Google Plus other info

[image: screen shot]

but there is no link to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're logged in to your Google Account. Go to [your profile](https://plus.google.com/me) in "Classic" G+.

"View profile as yourself".

[image: "View profile 'as yourself'"]

Click the "About" tab.

Scroll down until you see the "Basic Information" block.

[image: "Basic Information"]

Click "Edit".

[image: snippet of "edit Basic Information" tool]
Save when you're done.

Comment: why this new G+ doesnt support to change the "other name"

Comment: @kelum: Beats me. You'd have to ask Google. For what it's worth, this isn't the first of their products where the "new" version didn't include all of the functionality of the "old" version.